# How to use default merge tool on Mac

Tags: git, macos

```
    MY-MacBook-Pro:git-stuff MY$ git difftool
    MY-MacBook-Pro:git-stuff MY$
```

When I use the 'git difftool' command nothing happens.  It was working two days ago with FileMerge.  nothing has changed on my system since then.

Comment: Do you have any changes for difftool to report? What is the output when you run `git status`?

Comment: You're correct - I did not have changes at the time.  However I went ahead and ran these commands and now would like to undo them:                                git config --global merge.tool kdiff3                                                                       git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3

Comment: # Tell system when Xcode utilities live:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

                                                                                                                        # Set "opendiff" as the default mergetool globally:
git config --global merge.tool opendiff